# How to indicate in Procfile that app.py is in a different folder?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku, procfile

I was wondering if it is possible/necessary to indicate in the Procfile that app.py is in another directory. For example, my directory is like this:

```
root
│   Procfile
|
└───backend
│   │   app.py
```

Should the Procfile be

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

like usual? Or is there something that indicates app.py is in the backend directory? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I solved:

1. Create another file in the root folder like "main.py"

**main.py:**

```
from backend.app import app                                                               
if __name__ == "__main__":                                             
    app.run(debug=True)
```

2. Change ".env" file

```
FLASK_APP=main.py
```

3. change Procfile

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

directory now look like this:

```
root
│   Procfile
|   .env
|   main.py
└───backend
│   │   app.py
```

IT works for me I hope it works for you.